# How do I check the values of multiple elements (described by their IDs) using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (standardFlag == "ASCE")
{
  if (document.querySelectorAll('#Ss_param, #S1_param, #T0_param, #TL_param').value == "" ){
    alert("Please fill out all the required fields before generating your design spectrum");
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('Ss_param').value < document.getElementById('S1_param').value {
    alert("S1 must be less than Ss!");
  }
```

I'm trying to check whether either Ss_param, S1_param, T0_param or TL_param input ids hold any value. The second condition passes its own case which is how I know that the entire conditional is not faulty, but the first condition doesn't pass when it should. How do I rectify this?

Comment: You aren't using jQuery.

Comment: That's an _array_ (actually a NodeList).  You can't pretend it's a single object.

Comment: Check each element in turn. You can't get one value from multiple elements.

Comment: Your error message and question don't match up. Do you want to make sure *all* of the required fields are filled out or do you want to make sure *one* of the required fields is filled out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First and foremost: You should just look into a validation library.**

If you'd like to still approach it this way, I'd look into jQuery's `filter` method.

This would return only elements that have a value:

```
var $elementsWithValue = $('#Ss_param, #S1_param, #T0_param, #TL_param').filter(function(){ 
    return this.value.length > 0 
});
```

Then you can just check $elementsWithValue length.

Answer (score 1):

After reformatting your code to be more readable, it appears you're missing an ending close brace `}`, is this a typo in this question, or an error in your code?

Additionally your second condition is missing a closing parenthesis `)`.  Did you notice javascript errors when you open up the console in the browser you're testing on?

Once you solve that problem, you need to be aware that you're using native browser functions.  When you use `querySelectorAll` you get an array of objects back.  Calling `.value` on them will probably also be causing a javascript error.  You need to loop through each value, or use jQuery (which will arguably give you a more maintainable solution).

Using jQuery, this will give you the desired result:

```
if (standardFlag == "ASCE")
{
  var error = false;
  $.each(["Ss_param", "S1_param", "T0_param", "TL_param"], function(){
    if ($("#" + this).val() == ""){
      error = true;
      alert("Please fill out all the required fields before generating your design spectrum");
    }
  })

  if(!error && $("Ss_param").val() < $("#S1_param").val())
    alert("S1 must be less than Ss!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter if your id's always end's with `_param`

```
if ($('[id$="_param"]').filter(function(){
     return $(this).val() === "";  
   }).length > 0){
alert("Please fill out all the required fields before generating your design spectrum");
}
```

Comment: I don't think that code will work in real life, since he probably has some NON-required fields with `_param` IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get one value from multiple elements. Just compare them one at a time:

```
if (document.getElementById('Ss_param').value === ""
    || document.getElementById('S1_param').value === ""
    || document.getElementById('T0_param').value === ""
    || document.getElementById('TL_param').value === "" ){
```

(And check your JavaScript console for syntax errors. Your `else if` test is lacking a closing parenthesis.)